# google cloud platform cloud build rebuild cloud function not updated the content

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build, google-source-repositories

I put the file on Github and connected with Google Cloud Repository. 
Below is the .yaml file, when I update my index.js file, the Cloud Build rebuilds the Cloud Function, but why the content didn't get updated?
Manually setup for Cloud Function works

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
  args: ['install']
  dir: 'functions/autodeploy'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'function-1', '--trigger-http', '--runtime', 'nodejs10', '--entry-point', 'firstci']
  dir: 'functions/autodeploy'
```

Below is the function exported from index.js, now Cloud Function should output "test finally", but after rebuild, it still output "test 3rd time"

```
exports.firstci = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'setup pineline, test finally cloud build!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs 10 Runtime is still in beta. Try to put beta as following in your cloudbuild.yaml file and remove the 2 dir lines because it's not necessary.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn'
    args: ['install']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['beta','functions', 'deploy', 'function-1', '--trigger-http', '-- runtime', 'nodejs10', '--entry-point', 'firstci']
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this for a full day.  Ultimately, this is the yaml structure that successfully updated the Cloud Function content:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - my-function
      - '--trigger-topic'
      - my-topic
      - '--runtime'
      - dotnet3
      - '--entry-point'
      - Example.EntryPoint
      - '--region'
      - us-east1
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
      - '--source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/my-project/repos/github_dw_gcp/moveable-aliases/main/paths/cloud-functions/my-function'
```

This is called from a Cloud Build trigger after a push to a GCP Source Repository that is mirroed to GitHub.